# INVALID API KEY android Google Places

Tags: android, google-places-api, api-key, google-places

I've done all solutions that I can search. I enabled APIs that are related to my project and  made API keys(browser,android) slowly, and surely but not one is working. According to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlacesStatusCodes#KEY_INVALID) that my API key is malformed or missing. Is there a way to check if the value in my manifest is changing or getting null when I run my project?

Comment: are you copy and pasting your API keys or typing them out based off of visual? I only ask because, in my experience, I've found that copy and pasting the api keys from the dev dashboard works everytime.

Comment: I tried both copy-pasting and typing, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for the advice, I will try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a code that i found from tutorials. hope this help for the people having the same trouble.

I made a PlaceAPI class

```
public class PlaceAPI{

    private static final String TAG = PlaceAPI.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";

    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "key here";

    public ArrayList<String> autocomplete (String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;
        ArrayList<String> resultListid = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY.trim());
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Log.d(TAG, jsonResults.toString());

            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");//result

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));//geometry
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        //GET PLACEID
        try {

            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObjid = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArrayid = jsonObjid.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultListid = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArrayid.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArrayid.length(); i++) {
                resultListid.add(predsJsonArrayid.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }
}
```

and made an adapter PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter

```
class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    ArrayList<String> resultList;

    Context mContext;
    int mResource;

    PlaceAPI mPlaceAPI = new PlaceAPI();

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);

        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Last item will be the footer
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return resultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    resultList = mPlaceAPI.autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

then using the adapter in autocomplete:

```
autocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
        autocomplete.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.autocomplete_list_item));
        autocomplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get data associated with the specified position
                // in the list (AdapterView)
                place = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //Toast.makeText(this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are done with Google Setup then just try with this url, It's always working for me...

```
private String getPlacesApiUrl() {
    String url = "";
    String location = String.valueOf(currentLocation.latitude)+","+String.valueOf(currentLocation.longitude);       
    String radius = "5000";
    String type = "hospital";       
    String sensor = "false";
    String key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    try {
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json"
            + "?location=" +  URLEncoder.encode(location, "UTF-8")
            + "&type=" + URLEncoder.encode(type, "UTF-8")
            + "&radius=" + URLEncoder.encode(radius, "UTF-8")
            + "&sensor=" + URLEncoder.encode(sensor, "UTF-8")
            + "&key=" + URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("url",url);
    return url;
}
```

But make sure you are using **Browser Key**

Best of luck.

Comment: hi thanks for the solution, its working fine now. Do you know how to get the place's long&lat? thanks again sir, you are a life saver

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider "type: parameter in this method. Here you can pass any type listed here https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types.
And Please check out this tutorial also https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en.